# Can I place objects/variables on a React component? (getting ESLint error no-undef)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, react-native, eslint

This works perfectly fine in React Native, and also seems to run just fine in React. I assume because I'm using Create React App, I'm getting the ESLint error here but not with React Native. I can't disable no-undef as this will affect a lot of helpful checking, and also aren't sure that I can customize eslint to match how it is for React Native.

What's the best way to put a variable/object on a React component, if this isn't allowed? An example use case is where I want to reference this.props from a style object.

Ideally I want to avoid putting things on the render method as style objects can get very large (or is this the best way?)

Example of what I'd like to do (this works but with an ESLint error):

```
export class Test extends Component {
    style = {
        opacity: this.props.fade ? 0.5 : 1,

        color: "white",

        ...this.props.style
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div style={this.style}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: put it in consturtor state

Comment: no no don't put it in state. how did you create this react project?

Comment: sorry, just saw create-react-app. I just tried your exact code and I do not get an eslint error. are you sure your editor isn't using a different config than the one that comes with cra?

Comment: what version of create-react-app are you using (react-scripts)

Comment: thanks for the help - I'm using the latest version of create-react-app. I do have my own eslint config, but I thought cra was overwriting this because I was getting different errors in my cra project to my react-native ones with the same eslint config. i'll investigate a little further - is putting variables/objects on components like shown okay practise then?

Comment: yes it's fine, you're just missing babel in you're linter.

Answer (score 0):

Heyo!

You should get into the habit of extracting styles from your components.
In my projects I either have a file next to the component or within a subfolder.

You should probably also use `StyleSheet.create` to define several styles in one place. [link to docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html)

Having said that, I would either do one of these two:

```
// Styles/Test.js
export default StyleSheet.create({
  test: {
    color: 'white'
  },
  otherStyle: {},
  evenOtherStyle: {}
});

// Test.js
import styles from './Styles/Test';

export class Test extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div style={[
              styles.test,
              { opacity: this.props.fade ? 0.5 : 1 },
              ...this.props.style
            ]}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

OR, if you don't like the dynamic styles within the component, add a styling method OR do it within the constructor:

**Styling method:**

```
// Test.js
import styles from './Styles/Test';

export class Test extends Component {
    addStyles() {
      const opacityStyle = { opacity: this.props.fade ? 0.5 : 1 };
      return [styles.test, opacityStyle, ...this.props.style];
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div style={this.addStyles()}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Styling within constructor:**

```
// Test.js
import styles from './Styles/Test';

export class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.testStyles = [
        styles.test,
        { opacity: props.fade ? 0.5 : 1 },
        ...props.style
      ];
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div style={this.testStyles}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I have met same Errors, Just check Eslint and relation plugin then make sure it compatible with each other.